# Grouping and projection with mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following entity collection:

```
public class Branch
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ObjectId PartnerId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to group by PartnerId and select PartnerId, first not null Description and concatenate (SelectMany) all of the Discounts arrays in the group. Basically the desired result is an array of:

```
public class GroupProjection
{
    public ObjectId PartnerId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
}
```

Is it done with AggregateAsync API?

I've just started with mongodb and mongo c# driver. Is is possible using Linq or do I have to resort to JScript group definitions to build a pipeline?

I've took a look through [tests](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/Translators/AggregateProjectionTranslatorTests_Group.cs) for c# driver but it is not quite obvious, since they use internal helpers to build Bson documents with grouping criteria.

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB fluent API currently does not support the `SelectMany` extension method. However, you can workaround this.

```
var groupResult =
    await collection
        .Aggregate()
        .Group(
            x => x.PartnerId,
            g => new
            {
                PartnerId = g.Key,
                Description = g.First(x => x.Description != null).Description,
                Discounts = g.Select(x => x.Discounts)
            })
        .ToListAsync();

var result =
    groupResult
        .Select(x =>
            new GroupProjection
            {
                PartnerId = x.PartnerId,
                Description = x.Description,
                Discounts = x.Discounts.SelectMany(d => d)
            })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, should be good. I need some time to write tests for my queries though.

Comment: While testing the query I've ran into another problem, maybe you can take a look please.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670319/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-inheritance-mappings-and-serialization-issue

Comment: Apparently, to make this work, grouping or index is required also, or First statement will pick wrong element.